# Incorrect folder locations returned from SHGetPathFromIDList

Tags: windows, shell, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to restrict the users access to certain location (Windows, Program Files, etc.) and doing that by implementing the IFolderFilter interface.

Everything seems to be going fine up until the ShouldShow function gets called and then it all seems to fall apart. The initial folder that we pass in is that of C:\ProgramData\Company\App\Year and we see that, but the file dialog shows it hanging off Desktop which is why when I inspect the folders contained in the pidl are like C:\Users\Graham.Reeds\Desktop\Windows, C:\Users\Graham.Reeds\Desktop\Program Files, etc. This is seemingly preventing them from being matched up to the CSIDL_ variables I want to prevent the user from selecting.

I tried using `SHGetPathFromIDListEx` and `SHGetKnownFolderIDList` but VS2010 gives me the 'Identifier X is undefined' but I am including shlobj and link to Shell32.lib.

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ShouldShow(IShellFolder* sf, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFolder, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem)  
{  
    HRESULT resultCode = S_OK;  
    ULONG attributes = 0UL;  

    if (SUCCEEDED(sf->GetAttributesOf(1, &pidlItem, &attributes)))  
    {
        char szPath[_MAX_PATH];
        BOOL f = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlItem, szPath);
//      BOOL f = SHGetPathFromIDListEx(pidlItem, szPath, _MAX_PATH, 0);

        // FOLDERID_Windows / CSIDL_WINDOWS
        PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
//      if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_Windows, 0, 0, &pidl)))
        if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_WINDOWS, 0, 0, &pidl)))
        {
            HRESULT hres = sf->CompareIDs(0, pidlItem, pidl);
            if ((short)HRESULT_CODE(hres) == 0)
            {
                resultCode = S_FALSE;
            }
            ILFree(pidl);
        }
    }
    return resultCode;  
}
```

**What I need to do is to be able to prevent certain folders from appearing in the browse folder. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

`SHGetPathFromIDList` requires an absolute PIDL (one starting from the Desktop at the top of the namespace heirarchy and working down), but you are passing it `pidlItem` which is a single child PIDL (`pidlItem` is relative to `pidlFolder`, not the desktop).

Instead of using `SHGetPathFromIDList` you can use `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf` with the `SHGDN_FORPARSING` flag to get the full path of the item (e.g. `sf->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlItem, ...)`).

The same problem is happening with your `CompareIDs` call. `IShellFolder::CompareIDs` requires two PIDLs that are both relative to the specified folder, but you are trying to call it with one relative PIDL and one absolute one.

One solution would be to create an absolute PIDL out of `pidlFolder` and `pidlItem` using `ILCombine` and pass that to `CompareIDs`, but you would need to use the desktop folder to do the comparison (you obtain this from `SHGetDesktopFolder`) rather than using `sf`.

Comment: Thank you for that info, but the code to view the path is just so I can inspect the returned values and try to understand why I weren't hiding certain paths from the user.

Comment: @graham.reeds Long answer short - you can only compare two PIDLs if they both start from the same folder.

Comment: Thank you for expanding that, but it still skirts around the direct issue I am having: What do I need to do to prevent certain folders from appearing in the browse folder.  The simplest solution would be to check what is returned from SHBrowseForFolder, then compare that against a black list and throw up a message box if the folder is in that list.  Not ideal but would probably have taken me less time to write than this.

Comment: @graham.reeds I don't understand. You already know how to do it (`IFolderFilter::ShouldShow`). You just need to do it properly.

Comment: @graham.reeds By the way, the title of your question was *"Incorrect folder locations returned from SHGetPathFromIDList"*. If you don't want a particular question answered it's usually best not to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples (folder-relative PIDLs) to oranges (absolute PIDLs).  You need to convert the relative PIDL to an absolute PIDL before you can compare it to another item located in a different folder of the Shell namespace.

Try something more like this:

```
bool ArePIDLsTheSameItem(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl1, PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl2)
{
    if (ILIsEqual(pidl1, pidl2))
        return true;

    IShellFolder *sfDesktop = NULL;
    if (SHGetDesktopFolder(&sfDesktop) == S_OK)
    {
        HRESULT hres = sfDesktop->CompareIDs(0, pidl1, pidl2);
        sfDesktop->Release();

        if (HRESULT_CODE(hres) == 0)
            return true;
    }    

    return false;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ShouldShow(IShellFolder* sf, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFolder, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem)  
{  
    HRESULT resultCode = S_OK;

    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlWindows = NULL;
    //if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_Windows, 0, 0, &pidlWindows)))
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_WINDOWS, 0, 0, &pidlWindows)))
    {
        if (ArePIDLsTheSameItem(pidlWindows, pidlFolder))
        {
            // ignore anything inside the Windows folder itself...
            resultCode = S_FALSE;
        }
        else if (ILIsParent(pidlWindows, pidlFolder, FALSE))
        {
            // ignore anything inside a subfolder of the Windows folder...
            resultCode = S_FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolderAndItem = ILCombine(pidlFolder, pidlItem);
            if (pidlFolderAndItem)
            {
                if (ArePIDLsTheSameItem(pidlFolderAndItem, pidlWindows))
                {
                    // ignore the Windows folder itself...
                    resultCode = S_FALSE;
                }

                ILFree(pidlFolderAndItem);
            }
        }

        ILFree(pidlWindows);
    }

    return resultCode;  
}
```